# Can't run in browser on latest Linux and Mac with Java7u13 JFX2.2.5

Tags: java, linux, macos, cross-browser, javafx-2

I can't start JavaFX 2.2.5 applications in browser(all possible browsers) in Oracle Linux 6.3 x86 and latest MacOS. I have the latest Java 7 u 13 from Oracle.
Neither JavaFX Netbeans sample, my applications nor Ensamble(http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html) work.

The applications work if I start them as normal apps, but not from the browser.
Java works perfectly on those systems, just that I can't start JFX 2 in browsers.

What should be done? My clients need the flexibility of starting their apps from browsers.
It worked a few versions ago, but now I can't start them. Browsers tell me that I don't have Java. (they show that image with Java that redirects to the page from where I can download Java). I also tried to install just the JRE from that link. I have removed and reinstalled Java.

Is anyone else facing this problem?
Any help would be really useful.

I have also posted this on oracle forum: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2494131

Comment: Trying to run http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp fails. It doesn't detect Java neither. It seems that there is a problem with Java Browser Plugin. Ahhh.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, after installing JRE 7u13 on XP/sp3 (IE8), the "verify Java Version" page (http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) produces a Data Execution Prevention (DEP) exception

Answer (score 0):

I've got access to my customer's Mac machines.
My apologize. They had 7u12 on their Macs.

Happily enough, it seems that Oracle managed to get JFX working in browser with 7u13.

Regarding Linux, I finally got it to work, but don't forget about "firefox/plugins" and "firefox/plugin" (**the latest is wrong**). Oracle should update this error from their description available at: http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#enable